# expression in string to arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I'm a beginner to java and programming. 
I have a string `s="(((1+2))-((5+6))-((10+20))-((6-18))+((9+10)))"`
I would like to put it into a list or array.

Something like this,

`[(, (, (, 1, +, 2, ), ), -, (, (, 5, +, 6, ), ), -, (, (, 10, +, 20, ), ), -, (, (, 6, -, 18, ), ), _, (, (, 9, +, 10, ), ), )]`

Upon executing

`char[] a = String.valueOf("(((1+2))-((5+6))-((10+20))-((6-18))+((9+10)))").toCharArray();`

result is

`[(, (, (, 1, +, 2, ), ), -, (, (, 5, +, 6, ), ), -, (, (, 1, 0, +, 2, 0, ), ), -, (, (, 6, -, 1, 8, ), ), +, (, (, 9, +, 1, 0, ), ), )]`

**please note that 10 is coming as 1 and 0**

EDIT:

I would like to put it into a list of string

Something like this,

`List<String> ls = [(, (, (, 1, +, 2, ), ), -, (, (, 5, +, 6, ), ), -, (, (, 10, +, 20, ), ), -, (, (, 6, -, 18, ), ), _, (, (, 9, +, 10, ), ), )]`

Could somebody tell me how I can do it?

Comment: If you have it in a string, you can use [`s.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--).

Comment: @vincrichaud Seems a little too trivial for an answer. I thought the comment might draw out more requirements from the OP.

Comment: @Andreas Please remove the duplicate mark, because the OP does not want to convert it only to char array, there is limitations.

Comment: @Rowen So you don't want a char array. You want to break up your string into elements that might individually be longer than one character.

Comment: @Rowen You should know that `10` is not a char. If you try `char ss = '10'`, you get compile error.

Comment: @Andreas: Please check my edit. You will notice that its not a duplicate.

Comment: maybe you should also change the title and most of the rest regarding the `char[]` - it is still very confusing,.. sidenote: no need to call `valueOf` to convert a String to a String

Comment: @user6690200: Please see my edit

Comment: If you mean that literal numbers should be encoded as a single character, you will be limited to **positive** numbers **less than 65,536**.  Can you live with that?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson: yes

Comment: what do you really want now: is it single character, as asked by Kevin,  or String, as (partially) described in the question ???

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I'm expecting `[(, (, (, 1, +, 2, ), ), -, (, (, 5, +, 6, ), ), -, (, (, 10, +, 20, ), ), -, (, (, 6, -, 18, ), ), _, (, (, 9, +, 10, ), ), )]`.Forgive me i'm new to programming. hence some terminologies are new to me

Comment: @user6690200: i can only post an answer every 90 mins. Could you help on this post itself?

Comment: If you have a `char` value of, say,  24, how do you know if that means a left-paren `'('` or the number 24? I wish I had thought to raise that not-so-little detail earlier....

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger   The OP want a list or array of `String`, as he said in the updated question. Can you please reopen this question since it is not duplicate? I started a reopen vote, but seems no other users have noticed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is limited in positive numbers:

- first way:

  Use regex to find every string group which matches `(` or `)` or `+` or `-` or `*` or `\` or `at least one number character`.
- second way:

  Use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [regex lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split the string when

  - ahead is not number, behind is not number
  - or ahead is number, behind is not number
  - or ahead is not number, behind is number
- third way:

  Iterate on characters.

  - If it is a not digit, put into the list.
  - Else, loop to get a complete number.

Code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String example = "(((1+2))-((5+6))-((10+20))-((6-18))+((9+10)))";


    List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(|\\)|\\+|\\-|\\*|\\\\|\\d+"); // the back slashes are used for escaping
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        firstList.add(matcher.group());
    }

    // second way:
    List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList(
            example.split("(?<!\\d)(?!\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)(?=\\d)"));

    // third way
    List<String> thirdList = new ArrayList<>();
    char[] chars = example.toCharArray();
    for (int index = 0; index < chars.length; ) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(chars[index])) {
            thirdList.add(String.valueOf(chars[index])); // put into list if not digit
            index++;
        } else {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (Character.isDigit(chars[index])) {  // loop to get a complete number
                stringBuilder.append(chars[index]);
                index++;
            }
            thirdList.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is pretty better than the one i made on my side (iterate char by char and concatenate numbers). Good Job guy !

Comment: This method is a **lot** slower, though.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, I offer a solution without using regular expression:

```
public static List<String> split(String str) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder buf = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);

        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            if (buf == null)
                buf = new StringBuilder();
            buf.append(ch);
        } else {
            if (buf != null) {
                res.add(buf.toString());
                buf = null;
            }
            res.add(String.valueOf(ch));
        }
    }

    if (buf != null)
        res.add(buf.toString());

    return Collections.unmodifiableList(res);
}
```